# Flagging low quality posts or comments asking for clarification

Tags: discussion, flags

I've seen a lot of posts from students with some relatively easy question that doesn't have enough information or effort to answer. I think these are candidates for a low quality flag because nobody besides the OP can really make an effective edit.  But sometimes a prodding comment can get them to rewrite their question into something specific and useful.

Where is the line between these two? Is it almost always better to comment and flag if they don't improve it after some time? What is the convention?

Comment: I poke first. Given them a chance to learn how to use SO (and to figure out that we aren't here to do their homework but are willing to help them learn how to do it themselves.) On the other hand, I do sorta find myself wishing that the system tracked folks who have to be poked Every. Darned. Time.... or that it forbade the "user13491234" userIDs which make the repeat offenders harder to recognize.